# C++ struct that is implemented in CPP file and used in another class

Tags: c++, struct

What is the best way to make a struct in one class, that is implemented there and used in another class?

**Structs.h**

```
struct White{
   unsigned char r;
   unsigned char g;
   unsigned char b;
   Color() : r(255), g(255), b(255){}
};
struct Black{
   unsigned char r;
   unsigned char g;
   unsigned char b;
   Color() : r(0), g(0), b(0){}
};
White white; //works fine

Black black = {255, 255, 255}; //*error: data member initializer is not allowed!* (because of unsigned char maybe?)
**OR**
Black black; black.r = 255; //*error: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier!*
```

**anotherClass.cpp**

```
#include "Structs.h"
Structs *str = new Structs();
str->white.r //works, is 255
str->black.r //should be 255 too
```

Comment: I may just be ignorant, but these don't look like legal definitions (The ctor names for instance).

Comment: the line `Black blaqck = {255,255,255};` won't compile, because you have no constructor defined, that takes on an initializer list. try `Black black(255,255,255);` instead

Answer (score 3):

Your design looks wrong to me. You define "Black" and "White" to be different classes, whose objects have RGB values. And then you want a "Black" that has white values/properties? That sounds like defining a car, ripping off its wheels, giving it wings and 320 seats and pretending that a Boeing 757 is still a car.

What you normally want should be the following:

```
struct Color {
  unsigned char r;
  unsigned char g;
  unsigned char b;
};

Color black = {0,0,0};
Color white = {255,255,255};
Color blue = {0,0,255};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand the question but I would say that the ctor should White(): ... and Black():...  otherwise your header will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is with the constructor it should be the same as struct_name.**

Try

```
struct White{
   unsigned char r;
   unsigned char g;
   unsigned char b;
   White() : r(255), g(255), b(255){}
   void show(void)
   {
        cout << "RED:       " << r
             << "\tGreen:   " << g
             << "\tBlack:   " << b << endl;
   }
} white;

struct Black{
   unsigned char r;
   unsigned char g;
   unsigned char b;
   Black() : r(0), g(0), b(0){}
   void show(void)
   {
        cout << "RED:       " << r
             << "\tGreen:   " << g
             << "\tBlack:   " << b << endl;
   }
} black;

black.show();
white.show();
```